# How to default current date in DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a DE and I want to default the  current date value to one of the date field .

When I try doing its not allowing me to create the DE, it gives error. Is there any way we can do the same ?

Thanks and Regards,
Anumol Antony

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error and your DE structure? The default date in DE doesn’t usually throw any errors, so this could be something else. Do you create your DE from an existing DE?

Comment: Do you have the rights to create DataExtensions?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you add a field in DE with default current date:

1. create a field and set the type to date
2. click on the "-" icon next to Default Value field

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering this :)

Comment: No problem - if it helped, please mark the answer as accepted :-)

Comment: I'd like to add that you need to set the date field to nullable as well so your automation isn't required to write a date and the default (today's date) is written.